# Querying LDAP in VB.NET. I have the user account, and I want a list of groups the user in in

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group, directorysearcher

I know the SAMAccountName, and now want to populate a list of groups with entries that reflect this user's group membership across the whole directory. Here's my start, but I'm stumped:

```
        Dim path As String = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ldapPath")
        Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry(path)
        Dim search As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)
        Dim groupList As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" & _thisUser.UserName & ")"
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")
        'search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree

        For Each res As SearchResult In search.FindAll
        Next  ''Just doing this so I can look at "res" objects in debug
```

I've no idea how to traverse this. Please, any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, yourSamAccountName);

   if(user != null)
   {
        var groups = user.GetGroups();

        // iterate over groups or do whatever else you need to do....
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: That looks like it'll do the trick. I'll get back to you with my findings. Many thanks.

Comment: Hoorah!! I had to VB-ize it but yes what a fabulous pointer, than you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `memberOf` attribute has `distinguished name` syntax, and is  the DN of a group of which that user is a member. In other words, if the entry has a `memberOf` attribute, and that attribute has a value that is a valid group DN, then the user is already a member of that group.